# Cannot show map d3.js with JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, d3.js

I have the following code where I am trying to make a map of the world excluding Antarctica.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

    body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    svg {
      background-color: white;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 960,
        height = 1160;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("countries.json", function(error, world) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);
      console.log(world);
});

      svg.append("path")
          .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.subunits))
          .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to open the html page nothing appears, and the error it gives is:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I am following the tutorial from Mike Bostock that can be found here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/.
I already have tried numerous of commands and also trying to acces the file using the correspondent path of it.
These are the commands I tried (using the correspondent local host links of them):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer  
python3 -m http.server
npm install -g http-server
http-server -c-1
```

If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be great! I have checked my code a thousand of times and I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

**I tried to open the file in firefox now and the ERROR it gives is:**

```
TypeError: world.objects is undefined
```

Comment: Is `countries.json` in the same directory as your index.html?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the same directory!

Comment: The `svg.append` block has to be inside `d3.json` function.

Comment: The problem is in your countries.json, could your post it?

Comment: Yes, this is my JSON file: [link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/37h68) @Klaujesi

Comment: Your files is a .geojson and you use it as .topojson. They has no same internal structure. That's why you can access the propierties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First at all**: when you make a map must to define: map's center, scale and projection.  (This's word map no need center)

**Second**: your data is a geojson and you use it as .topojson. Allways try to use .topojson:

- Original file (geojson): **561 Kb**
- Converted file (topoJSON): **75 Kb**

Here you can find your map converted:

[TopoJSON Word Map](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmqp8lttg31au31/word.topojson?dl=0)

And here the complete code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    svg {
      background-color: white;
    }
    .county {
        fill:#696;
        stroke:#666;
        stroke-width:1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- D3 Base -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!-- TopoJSON Library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.20/topojson.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 960,
        height = 1160;

    var scal = (1 << 10) / 2 / Math.PI;     //<-- Scale
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(scal).translate([width / 2, height / 2]);           //<-- Projection
    var center = projection(cent);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("word.topojson", function(error, world) {
      if (error) return console.error(error);

      var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.collection);
      svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(countries.features)
        .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("class", "county")      //<-- Class to style your countries
          .attr("d", path);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thats will give you something like this:

[image]

**Recommendations**

- Phyton SimpleHTTPServer, work well but it's better to go with something more solid. Install WAMP if you are on Windows or XAMPP if you are on Linux
- Try diffents browsers, I've found some bug on Firefox with SVG and Maths. Overall projection maths and representation.-

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I'm going to try this! :)

Comment: What does the "var scal = (1 << 10) / 2 / Math.PI; " do? I am trying to project some lines between longitude and latitude but all the lines project mirrored in the svg object... Do you maybe know why this happens?

Comment: Scale your map, change the '10' by '12' or '20' and check your map. You'll note how its works ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Gerardo Furtado is correct.  You need to wrap the svg in the d3.json call.  This uses uk.json for example:

```
    d3.json("https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/uk.json", function(error, world) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(world);

    svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.subunits))
    .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));  
    });
```

When I plug this into your code, I can see a small map of the UK.

Comment: you work with uk.json from Mike's page. He work with: countries.json. We must see the content. Maybe he is not using: world.objects.subunits

Comment: I think @Klaujesi is right, because I tried to implement it with this code and it didn't work either...